# How to use CNN to predict the center coordinates of a hole

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, regression

I have a dataset containing 2000 images that look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm4tN.jpg

The goal is to use CNN to predict the center point (x,y) of the rounded rectangle shape. Center points associated with training images are provided as training labels.

Here is the general flow of my program:

1. Crop the original image (2592 x 1944) into Region of interests (ROIs) of (2092 x 544)
2. Use data augmentation techniques (rotation, gaussian noise, brightness, zoom, shifting) to increase the image quantity to 20000.
3. Crop the augmented ROIs images to 64x64 numpy array (aspect ratio is no preserved)
4. Use 10% of the dataset as validation set
5. Fit the above images into a CNN model. I use the default Adam optimizer. The model summary and train result are in this file
   https://gofile.io/?c=G9z8Y7"
6. Evaluate the model on the whole dataset + 100 test images
7. Compare the prediction results with ground truths

I use val_mae metric to measure success. I was not satisfied with the prediction results although the val_mae reached 0.61. The highest x gap is 3.4 pixels and only 50% of the images achieved my goal (x_gap < 1px and y_gap < 1px).

How should i tune my CNN model to achieve my target

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you used augmentation techniques? because if these images are gonna look the same, a simple blob/contour detector with opencv followed by computing min area rectangle and its centre will be effective. May i know the reason for choosing CNN's over those methods ?

Comment: Thanks venkat. The reason to use data augmentation is to cope with factors such as lighting condition, image noises, image rotation... Another reason is that i don't need to change the detection logic when different images appear. Finally, i want to verify the feasibility of CNN in this application.

Comment: may I also know how is the cropping done? it must be 100% accurate I believe. Also please provide the information on the model architecture if possible.

Comment: the cropping process is really simple
crop_img = original_img[y_margin:-y_margin, x_margin:-x_margin].copy()

Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", input_shape=(64,64,1))
Activation('relu')
Conv2D(128, kernel_size=2, padding="same")
Activation('relu')

Conv2D(256, kernel_size=2, padding="same")
Activation('relu')
MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))

Dropout(0.25)
Flatten()
Dense(128)
Activation('linear')
Dense(2)

Comment: Seems to be fine. Generally to tune the model, we generally tune the optimizer, learning rate, dimension of the input, depth/channels of the convolution network. 
In your case, i would recommend you to start with varying the dimension of the input, then the learning rate, then the layers in the convolution network.

Comment: I agree with you. Do you think that my resizing process from 2092 x 544 to 64x64 has negative effects on the learning result. I could not preserve the aspect ratio of training images.  Is there any way to preserve the aspect ratio without cropping a part of the rounded rectangle?

Comment: probably yes.. if its classification then resizing would affect much. but in your case, its more localization, so better to preserve the aspect ratio. downsample it to lets say 128*32 or 256*64 and just to maintain almost 1:4 ratio and try the convolution.